# A scrambled grid

Tags: wordplay, word-search

Here is a 10x10 grid of letters where the letters on each row have been scrambled randomly:

[image]

In the unscrambled grid, each cell is part of a word at least 5 letters long. Words are written from left to right or from top to bottom, and all the words are connected together. What is the original grid, and what are all the words it contains?

Here's a copyable version of the scrambled grid:

```
A   E   S   K   L   N   A   O   P   O

E   N   F   D   E   K   L   I   E   L

A   N   A   C   U   K   T   T   T   G

I   O   N   D   O   H   A   I   M   L

T   N   O   S   S   T   L   I   L   O

E   B   U   E   D   D   I   C   O   O

S   G   I   O   A   D   I   A   M   N

L   S   D   V   M   Y   K   E   E   E

R   E   A   B   O   L   M   A   L   N

Y   S   C   S   A   S   R   Y   E   O
```

I didn't realize how hard this puzzle was when I posted it, so I'm adding a hint. Here's the grid where some letters have been filled in. All you have to do is find the missing letters:

[image]

Comment: Does "connected" mean "each word overlaps with at least one letter with another one"?

Comment: @Runemoro Can some or all letters in any cell be used for multiple words or are they used only once?

Comment: @kanchirk: They can be used twice, even for words in the same direction.

Comment: @dmg: It means that all words overlap with another, and that all words are connected somehow. If you would draw lines over each word, it would form a single shape.

Comment: @Runemoro Thank you.. That is an interesting hint.

Comment: @Runemoro The puzzle as it's stated seems like too hard, maybe you can give hints (like a crossword puzzle) for some of the words.

Comment: @Anachor I don't know about that.  Let's see what the bounty brings in first.  Runemoro, when the words overlap, do they follow the usual word search convention that words travelling in the same direction in the same row will only be connected at the last character?

Comment: 20 minutes later and I'm with @Anachor, this is tough.  There are lots of options for the words in the horizontals.  Line 3 from the top has the least options at 14 based on this site http://www.wordplays.com/word-jumble-solver/.

Comment: @LeppyR64: No, I was not aware of this convention. I'll add some hints soon though.

Comment: I'm confused, all words are 5 or more letters, right? Is every letter in two words? Does every column match up with words? At most there could be 40 words? 2 per row and 2 per column? Or am I misunderstanding how they are connected?

Comment: @Raystafarian: Yes, words are at least 5 letters. It is a word search, so words can overlap, but not every cell is part of two words. When the grid is unscrambled, there will be words written horizontally and words written vertically, and they are all connected (if you draw a line over them, it will make a single shape).

Comment: Does there needs to be at least 3 words per row, so they all connect?

Comment: @Raystafarian No.

Comment: Even with @LeppyR64 's insight for focusing on line 3, there are very little other educated guesses to make to narrow down the possibilities.
It would help greatly if we know the number of horizontal and/or vertical words present in the puzzle, or the number of connections in each row and/or column, or even a restriction on the scrambling (e.g. none of the letters are currently in their correct positions).

Comment: Or: is there at least one word in every row (column)? Or a mega hint could be, how long is the longest word used?

Comment: Brand new to the site, love this puzzle. Can a letter be used in 3 words?

Comment: This is wrecking havoc on the brute force unscrambling program I wrong in Lua on no iPod. Why not a *5x5* grid? Or at the most *7x7* :(

Comment: Wrote* on iPod*

Comment: I think the copy able version is in the wrong order.

Comment: Maybe to make it easier you should give us another grid where the columns are scrambled instead.

Comment: The reason I didn't post any hints earlier is that I had lost the original (solution) grid. I managed to re-create it out of memory today, though, and I've added a hint to the puzzle. I'll add more hints tomorrow if no one gets it by then.

Comment: @Runemoro You'll need to be more careful. There's nothing like working hard on a puzzle, only to find that the OP isn't sure whether your answer is correct because he forgot what the answer was!

Comment: @Raystafarian As the OP hasn't defined any limits "NEPAL" fits too. And if i understand the riddle correctly, you can use more than the last letter of the word so "NE[PAL]OOKA" should be possible. And you can fill the rest of a line with vertical words.

Comment: @Sleafar so you could use 9 letters for 2 words and then just use whatever is left for a vertical word? Did not understand that.

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes, and even more than that. You **must** use one of the letters of the horizontal word for another vertical word, to fullfill "all the words are connected together". Again, if I understood the riddle correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One bugfix later, I think I have a solution:

> Grid (I omitted some words from the list below):
>  [image]
>
> ```
>  Horizontal:        Vertical:
>  
>  0, 0: NEPAL        0, 1: EIGHT
>  0, 4: LOOKS        0, 2: PENNIES
>  1, 0: FIELD        0, 3: ALTITUDE
>  1, 5: KNEEL        0, 6: ONTOLOGY
>  2, 4: ATTACK       0, 8: SECOND
>  3, 3: IDIOM        0, 9: ALKALI
>  4, 3: TOOLS        0, 9: ALKALIN
>  5, 1: DEUCE        1, 0: FULSOME
>  6, 0: MISDO        1, 0: FULSOMELY
>  6, 5: AGAIN        3, 6: OLOGY
>  7, 2: SEEDY        5, 1: DIMES
>  8, 2: ABNORMAL     5, 2: ESSAY
>  8, 4: NORMA        5, 7: BALMS
>  8, 4: NORMAL       5, 8: DIVAS
>  9, 3: ACROSS       5, 9: INKLE
>  9, 4: CROSS
>  9, 4: CROSSE
> ```
>
> The words are from this wordlist: http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/

Comment: I worked on this for 3 days only to realize I don't have proper nouns like "Nepal" in my dictionary..... gosh darn it. Great job though.

Comment: No wonder I couldn't do it, I didn't know proper nouns were allowed either! Good job!

Comment: @Dsel May I ask which dictionary you used? And thanks to all.

Comment: @Sleafar I used the dictionary from LetterPress, it happened to be one of the first links I came across when I went googling for a word list. Here's the link https://github.com/atebits/Words